# Struggling with Vapor Client

Tags: swift, http, client, vapor

I'm trying to make a simple get request to Google Places API from my vapor web service.

This is what my controller looks like:

```
import Vapor
import HTTP
import VaporPostgreSQL

final class MainController {

var currentDroplet: Droplet!

func addRoutes(drop: Droplet) {

    currentDroplet = drop
    drop.get("places",String.self, String.self, handler: getNearbyPlaces)

}

func getNearbyPlaces(request: Request, lat: String, long: String) throws -> ResponseRepresentable {

    let googleAPIKey = "MY_KEY"
    let googlePlacesBaseURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch"

    let url = googlePlacesBaseURL + "/json?location=\(lat),\(long)&radius=500&types=food&key=" + googleAPIKey

    print(url)

    let apiResponse = try drop.client.get(url)

    print(apiResponse)

    return apiResponse.json != nil ? apiResponse.json! : "Something went bad"


   }
}
```

It should be as simple as that, however when I call it, the request keeps hanging for a long time and then it returns 500.
Note that the printed **url** in the console does work fine directly in the browser.
I couldn't figure out a useful way to catch and debug any errors too.

Comment: is the url right encoded?

Comment: Yep. The url logged to the console works fine in the browser

Comment: the browser converts the url on its own into the right format - if you call via program you maybe need to encode it

Comment: call it with curl on command line then it should work also

Comment: It works as well. It seems to be exactly as described in Vapor Client docs:
https://vapor.github.io/documentation/http/client.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add `import Foundation` and `drop.client = FoundationClient.self` to `main.swift` to get a similar call to work.

Comment: That did it. Just like magic. Thanks a lot!
Can't believe they do not specify that in the Docs...

Comment: The `drop.client` is `let`. It can not be assigned. Any other solution?